# How to scroll to the correct div with fixed Navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap affixed navbar, but when i try to scroll to a div, the navbar overlays the div text, so i can't read it.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Post your code here, or post your link along your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i can not know of your scenario from very little code provided. Anyways i have come up with related demo here. Have a look, see if it helps you.

Here in following we would scroll Down to **Header Level 3** content having class `scrollStop`.

**My Approach:**

**1)** Finding position of **Header Level 3** from top using `offset().top`

**2)** Finding `outerHeight()` of **< header >** having class `header`.

**3)** Now **Top Position - Header Height** helps us to get actual position to scroll by removing header's `height`.

**4)** Finally animate scroll to that position.

**<kbd>[Working : Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/r9u889kb/)</kbd>**

```js
$(".scroll").click(function()
{
    var scrollPos = $(".scrollStop").offset();
    scrollPos = scrollPos.top;
    var headerHeight = $(".header").outerHeight();
    var actualPos = scrollPos - headerHeight;
    $("body,html").animate({'scrollTop': actualPos});
});
```

```css
body
{
    margin:0px;
}
.header
{
    margin:0px;
    display:block;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:rgba(180,30,30,0.7);
}

.container
{
    margin:55px auto 0px auto;    
    background:#ccc;
    width:90%;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.title h1
{
    text-align:center;
}

.container > div
{
    display:block;
    width:90%;
    background:#2b2937;
    color:#eee;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px auto;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.scroll
{
    position:fixed;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    background:#34D2E3;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    right:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
</div>
<span class="scroll">Scroll Down<br> Click</span>
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Dummy HTML Text</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

    <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

    <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

    <ol>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
       <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ol>

    <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

    <h3 class="scrollStop">Header Level 3</h3>

    <ul>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
       <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
    </ul>

    <pre><code>
    #header h1 a { 
        display: block; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 80px; 
    }
    </code></pre>
    
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>    
        
    
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>  
        
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it using the [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin, I changed my code like so:

```
$("#a-politica-comercial").click(function() {
    $('body').scrollTo($('#politica-comercial'), 800, {offset:-110});
});
```

I changed the `offset` to reduce some pixels in the final position, so now I have the `div` with the correct text!

Thanks anyways!

Comment: Also you could do is get height of header and subtract it. Like subtract `$(".header").outerHeight()` from the `offset().top` of targeted element.

Comment: @divy3993 Sorry, i didn't understand, can you explain? Based in my code?